# $x^{2}+y^{2}=3(2023)^{z}+77$: to prove that if $4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 4\mid x^{2},y^{2}$

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

This is a math Olympiad problem, and actually, I was in it.
$x^{2}+y^{2}=3(2023)^{z}+77$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Prove that if $4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 4\mid x^{2},y^{2}$
> then find all $(x,y,z)$ solutions to the equation.

**My attempt :**

A claim:
$3(2023)^{z}+77$ Is divisible by $4$ iff $z$ is even.

But I can't prove this claim.
**Do not use any modular arithmetic**

Comment: There's a typo in the question title.  Please correct it.

Comment: Where ? I don’t see it

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會Do it yourself if you're that bothered.

Comment: No, the typo makes ambiguity in the question so you can't fix it unless you know what the original problem is. Is the question supposed to be with $7$ or $4$?

Comment: $$4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 4\mid x^{2},y^{2}$$ is trivial.  In the question title, $4$ divides $x^2+y^2$ but in the question body, the divisor becomes $7$, which is the correct one?

Comment: The original question was with 7 instead of 4. OP please don't change your question after posting it!

Comment: I have no idea what the question is.  Is the thing about $2023$ connected in some way to the divisibility question?  How?

Comment: Excuse me, 4 instead of 7.

Comment: @Mike I'm with you about keeping the question untouched, but you can apply the same argument for $7$, whose quadratic residue is $0$, $1$, $2$ and $4$.  Besides, `\mid` gives better spacing: $4 \mid 0$.

Comment: @Yassir  Can you clarify your question?  It really doesn't make sense as written.  As you can see from the comments, nobody can sort out if you are asking about division by $4$ or by $7$.  Nor does the part about $2023$ appear to have anything to do with anything else.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Yes GNU Its an easy question either way.

Comment: I corrected it now you can easily understand the two questions @lulu

Comment: Still not clear.   What's the relation between these questions?  They all seem quite easy.. What have you tried for any of them?

Comment: Its the same question they have the same initial condition which is The equation with $2023$.You know what i will delete the second question

Answer (score 2):

**The original question was with 4** The only thing you need is $4|(x^2+y^2)$. If $4$ divides $x^2+y^2$ then $4$ must divide both $x$ and $y$. Indeed: Then as all odd squares are $1 \mod 4$, if either $x$ or $y$ are odd then $(x^2+y^2) \mod 4$ is either $1$ or $2$. So both $x$ and $y$ must be even i.e., multiples of $2$. Which gives $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both multiples of $2^2=4$.

**To see mod 7**, this follows from the fact that $-1$ is not a square mod 7. i.e., the only way $x^2+y^2$ could divide $7$ without both $x^2,y^2$ dividing 7 would be if $y^2 \mod 7 = (-1)×x^2\mod 7$ which would imply that $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, which it is not. This can be easily checked directly.

Comment: You are correct, of course, about the divisibility by $4$.  Let's give the OP a chance to sort out your remarks and adjust the Question accordingly as the issue of divisibility by $7$ is important to them.  We are only minutes into the appearance of that post.

Comment: i don't think that modular arithmetic is allowed, because we didn't study it yet

Answer (score 0):

$3\equiv -1\mod(4)$

$2023\equiv -1\mod (4)$

$77\equiv 1\mod(4)$

$\Rightarrow$ $3(2023)^z+77\equiv(-1)(+1)+1\equiv 0\mod(4)$

If z is even.

For second question:

$2023=7\times 17^2\equiv 0\mod 7$

$\Rightarrow 3(2023)^z+77\equiv 0 \mod(7)$